# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a **react** tutorial to build a **chat application**. But I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`  in the below code. I am getting this error in the 2nd line of the `formattedConversations` function. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.  Please help me to solve this issue.

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import useLocalStorage from '../hooks/useLocalStorage'
import { useContacts } from './ContactsProvider'


const ConversationsContext = React.createContext()

export function useConversation() {
  return useContext(ConversationsContext)
}

export function ConversationsProvider({ children }) {

  const [conversations, setConversations] = useLocalStorage('conversations', [])
  const { contacts } = useContacts()

  function createConversation(recepients) {
    setConversations(prevConversations => {
      return [...prevConversations, { recepients, messages: [] }]
    })
  }

  const formattedConversations = conversations.map(conversation => {
    const recepients = conversation.recepients.map(recepient => {
      const contact = contacts.find(contact => {
        return contact.id === recepient
      })
      const name = (contact && contact.name) || recepient
      return { id: recepient, name }
    })

    return { ...conversation, recepients }
  })

  const value = {
    conversations: formattedConversations,
    createConversation
  }

  return (
    <ConversationsContext.Provider value={value} >
      {children}
    </ConversationsContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: I would guess that `conversation` doesn't have a field `recipients`.  Why don't you try logging the value of `conversation` to the console to investigate further?

Comment: I would suggest that you put `value` inside a state. Modify the state with `useEffect` based on when it needs to happen.

Comment: When your component mounts first time, `recipients` will be empty. Maybe optional chaining will help you.

Comment: I tried logging the value of  `conversation` to the console, but I got nothing in the console. It logs nothing in the console (only errors).

Answer (score 0):

This error says `recepients` are not set as an array in your `conversation`.

Put a `console.log` inside a component ex. `ConversationsProvider`,

```
  export function ConversationsProvider({ children }) {
    ... all your code
    console.log(conversations)
    return ...
  }
```

This way you'll know anytime you changed this conversations and why your `recepients` is not properly set as a array.

You have multiple places of changing it, ex. `createConversation`, `formattedConversations`, so hard to say without looking at your implementation code, you can debug the consumer component which uses `useConversation` as well.

Comment: I tried `console.log(conversations)` in `ConversationsProvider` function, but I am not getting anything in console.

Comment: That means `ConversationsProvider` is not even used.

Comment: Then what should i do now? Should i post the consumer component which uses `useConversation`?